# How can I reset a local branch to the remote tracking branch without specifying the latter?

Tags: git, jenkins

If I have a local branch and a remote branch that have gotten out of sync, it's easy to reset the local branch to the remote state by running

```
$ git reset --hard origin/foo
```

However, there are cases when this is unwieldy, specifically if I'm running a script that needs to reset whatever branch I have currently checked out to the remote state (I have this issue in a Jenkins script right now).

What I need is a command that does 'find out the remote tracking branch and reset the local branch to whatever that is'. Let's assume that there is always a remote tracking branch.

Simply applying 'origin' won't work, because I have multiple remotes. The closest I got was

```
git reset --hard `git branch -vv | grep "^*" | grep -P -o "(?<=\[).*(?=\])"`
```

...but that seems silly, given git's million commands, there must be an easier way.

Comment: Track remote branch in combination with pull force ff-only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git provides `@{u}` as a shorthand for the upstream, so we can use:

```
$ git reset --hard @{u}
```

or

```
$ git reset --hard @{upstream}
```

for exactly this kind of problem. See also http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches.

Comment: Thanks for this, you can & should accept your own answer btw.